# Push upgrade app for second generation packages?

Tags: managed-package, deployment, metadata-api, 2gp, push-upgrade

Based on the [Scheduling Push Upgrades](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/push_upgrade_scheduling.htm) and the [Push a Package Upgrade](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/push_upgrade_intro_2GP.htm) documentation, while Salesforce UI to schedule push upgrades is available for first generation packages (1GP), for second generation packages (2GP) there is presently only a set of APIs.

Before I go off and create my own app to schedule/monitor 2GP push upgrades (looks like multiple days fo work to do):

1. Any expectation that Salesforce will build UI for this soon?
2. Anyone about to release some open source for this or post a free app on https://appexchange.salesforce.com/?
3. Does a commercial product have this capability already?
4. Or if you are *seriously* interested in sharing the work of building such an app comment here and we can figure out a way of getting in touch.

**PS** Also see [Can objects such as PackagePushRequest be made available in a scratch org?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/347352/can-objects-such-as-packagepushrequest-be-made-available-in-a-scratch-org)

Comment: Hi Keith, I'm currently on a finishing stage with one the Second generation Managed Package. It won't be free, but we plan to have Push updates and I would gladly part take in an open source project to ease up usage of APIs.

Comment: don't know regarding roadmap for it, theoretically it can be a next step for Development Center

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a Salesforce Labs application called [Package Visualizer](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N4V00000FNBc0UAH) that offers, as part of its functionality, scheduling push upgrades for 2GP managed packages.

The [user guide](https://salesforce.quip.com/f3SWA340YbFH#OUNACAitjU9) for the application describes its push-related functionality. One thing to note is

> You can only select up to 10,000 Subscribers for a single Push Upgrade Request

*Disclosure: I am a Salesforce employee, but am not an author of and have not used this application.*

Comment: Hi David, Looks like what I'm looking for. Think you may have just saved me from wasting a lot of time... And not expecting more than 10,000 subscribers any time soon.

Comment: ... and my fist impression having installed this is that it looks great.

Answer (score 2):

I decided to [publish my own application on AppExchange](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N4V00000IZEacUAH) which allows to perform push upgrades for 2GMP and some more features, like extract information about Subscribers or Versions so that we could compare of how many subscribers different packages have.

I used that data to provide some Google Charts to my customer, however, I haven't included Google Charts functionality to the package.

Also I am thinking to allow options to install the package on one org and manage all devhubs from that single org by switching between orgs (this I have implemented in the beta version which is not yet published on AppExchange, the published version requires the org to have the Dev Hub feature enabled as well as 2GMP).

Feel free to comment out on this app.

Comment: Used it after using the Package Visualizer from Salesforce apps. This one is much better and has more features. Thanks for sharing

Comment: Thanks @vishesh, could you please leave a review on AppExchange review if you liked the package?

Comment: Already did. Thanks for building this.

Comment: thanks. Strange that I didn't get a notification, or maybe I missed it.

Answer (score 1):

> Any expectation that Salesforce will build UI for this soon?

No. As you probably know, Safe Harbor rules. They won't announce a UI for this until it's nearly ready. If you have an NDA and an inside contact, you can ask them yourself. I have such access, but I wouldn't be able to share that knowledge without written consent, so even if I asked for you, I would be neither able to confirm nor deny the possibility of a future UI.

> Anyone about to release some open source for this or post a free app on https://appexchange.salesforce.com/?

I don't know of anyone doing it, but it would be pretty trivial to write.

> Does a commercial product have this capability already?

Again, I don't know of anyone aside from ytik that's working on such a thing, and only because they commented on your question.

> Or if you are *seriously* interested in sharing the work of building such an app comment here and we can figure out a way of getting in touch.

You know how to reach me if you want to. Maybe ytik, you, and I could all collaborate on this (or anyone else who's interested).